# Qt c++ application scraping

Tags: c++, qt, screen-scraping

I would like to interact with an opened qt window (wrote in c++)  using code. The code would act like a user and will be completely independent of the code of the qt window. Something like web scraping but with qt (which is much more complicated).The first thing I’m  attempting to do is to mimic a click on a push button.

My first intuition was to add some c++ code to the existing code at runtime and execute something like « pushButton.click(); ». After some few searches I tried to use dynamic shared library. The library would implement the code of the button I want to click on, and would be dynamically added to the existing c++ code. This solution could work but seems to be very complicate and not portable. Furthermore I would like the solution to be very independent of the window code.

Of course the qt code of the window will be accessible from the scraping code side.

Are some other solutions more practical ?

EDIT:
GammaRay seems to work fine. I manage to perform a click on a pushButton using the GUI. However, GammaRay doesn't seem to provide a command line interface form. As we can read in the official documentation:

The GammaRay client is available in two forms:

- as a standalone application as depicted in the following screenshot
- as Qt Creator plugin (for Qt Automotive Suite only)

Is there any possibility to perform a click using GammaRay and without GUI? Are some other solutions work using code only?

Comment: see GammaRay: https://doc.qt.io/GammaRay/index.html

Comment: Thank you. Is GammaRay compatible with qt 4.8?

Comment: You might use `QTestLib` - a Qt module for unit testing. It allows to mimic some user actions such as mouse clicks, double clicks, moves etc. https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtestlib-manual.html

Comment: GammaRay seems to work fine with qt version 4.8. I manage to perform a click on a pushButton using the GUI. I would like to perform it using the command line interface. Is this possible?

Comment: The QTestLib module doesn't seem to be able to connect to a running window... I need something like GammaRay that is able to connect to a running window using his pid, but that also provide command line or code usage like QTestLib. A mix between both would make the job...

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of GammaRay is introspection and not automation. I recommend to use Squish (https://www.froglogic.com/de/squish/editions/qt-gui-test-automation/), depending on the required licenses the price is not so high.

If you don't want to spent the money, then you have to create your own IPC Interface with Remote Commands.